# Allure Reports are not getting created when running the tests with cucumber - capybara - selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara, allure

I am trying to run the cucumber test cases along with capybara and selenium webdriver. While running I am getting the following error even if all the test cases are passed. As a result, cucumber jenkins job is getting failed. When I try to open the allure report, it is blank.

Can any one help me out from this ?

log trace:

> 3 scenarios (0 failed, 3 passed) 12 steps (0 failed, 12 passed)
>   1m8.278s
>
> wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/capybara-3.12.0/lib/capybara/node/document.rb:31:in
>   title'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/capybara-3.12.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:738:in
>   block (2 levels) in class:Session'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/capybara-3.12.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in
>   block (2 levels) in '
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/allure-ruby-adaptor-api-0.7.2/lib/allure-ruby-adaptor-api/builder.rb:128:in
>   block (3 levels) in build!'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/builder.rb:391:in
>   insert'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/builder.rb:375:in
>   method_missing'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/allure-ruby-adaptor-api-0.7.2/lib/allure-ruby-adaptor-api/builder.rb:126:in
>   block (2 levels) in build!'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/builder.rb:293:in
>   initialize'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/allure-ruby-adaptor-api-0.7.2/lib/allure-ruby-adaptor-api/builder.rb:125:in
>   new'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/allure-ruby-adaptor-api-0.7.2/lib/allure-ruby-adaptor-api/builder.rb:125:in
>   block in build!'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/allure-ruby-adaptor-api-0.7.2/lib/allure-ruby-adaptor-api/builder.rb:124:in
>   each'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/allure-ruby-adaptor-api-0.7.2/lib/allure-ruby-adaptor-api/builder.rb:124:in
>   build!'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/allure-cucumber-0.6.1/lib/allure-cucumber/formatter.rb:144:in after_features'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/formatter/ignore_missing_messages.rb:11:in
>   method_missing'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/formatter/legacy_api/adapter.rb:136:in
>   after'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/formatter/legacy_api/adapter.rb:41:in
>   block in initialize'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:34:in
>   block in broadcast'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:34:in
>   each'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:34:in
>   broadcast'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/cucumber-core-3.2.1/lib/cucumber/core/event_bus.rb:40:in
>   method_missing'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/configuration.rb:33:in
>   notify'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:76:in
>   run!'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:34:in
>   execute!'
>   /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/bin/cucumber:9:in
>   ' /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/cucumber:23:in
>   load' /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/cucumber:23:in
>
> ' /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in
>   eval' /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in
>   ' Took 70 seconds (1:10) cucumbers Failed

Comment: Use code format for better formatting your question.

Comment: Are you getting XML output first ?

Comment: Line 128 of /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/allure-ruby-adaptor-api-0.7.2/lib/allure-ruby-adaptor-api/builder.rb is calling Capybaras `title` method instead of the one it expects. You aren't including Capybara::DSL in the global scope are you??

Comment: @Thomas  This happens only when i add,

include Capybara::DSL

in the env.rb file in cucumber tests.

Comment: @NareshSekar Ok - so you are including it -- where are you including it to?  Edit your question and add the relevant section of env.rb.  I'm guessing you're seeing a message like "including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!" which should have been your first clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are including Capybara::DSL in the global scope. Any relatively modern version of Capybara will print a warning to the console like "including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!" specifically because it will have all sorts of strange side effects. This is because when you just do

```
include Capybara::DSL
```

outside of any classes or modules you end up including all of Capybaras methods on every object in your project. That's not what you want. It's impossible to say exactly what you need to put where without looking at your project, but assuming you have a normal project you probably want to put

```
World(Capybara::DSL)
World(Capybara::RSpecMatchers)
```

in your env.rb, or just require 'capybara/cucumber' like instructed - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#using-capybara-with-cucumber - which will get things set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Walpole, 
When i do `World(Capybara::DSL)`, I cant use Capybara's methods inside my test scripts. When i try to use `page` method of capybara's, I am getting error like **`page` method is not found**,
but when i use `include Capybara::DSL`, page method is getting recognised and i get my scripts running smooth. Any idea on why i am facing this behaviour.

Comment: @NareshSekar That really all depends on how your project is set up.  All your scenarios should be run in a World so Capybaras methods should be available there, read https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/state/#world-object.  I don't know what your World objects are. Are the "test scripts" actually cucumber scenarios?  Note: you can always call `Capybara.current_session` which is what `page` does.